# How can you two-way bind a checkbox to an individual bit of a flags enumeration?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, enums, bit-manipulation

For those who like a good WPF binding challenge:

I have a nearly functional example of two-way binding a `CheckBox` to an individual bit of a flags enumeration (thanks Ian Oakes, [original MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c05b7e7e-25cd-4a41-8bf5-e35d2caff797/)).  The problem though is that the binding behaves as if it is one way (UI to `DataContext`, not vice versa). So effectively the `CheckBox` does not initialize, but if it is toggled the data source is correctly updated. Attached is the class defining some attached dependency properties to enable the bit-based binding. What I've noticed is that ValueChanged is never called, even when I force the `DataContext` to change.

**What I've tried:** Changing the order of property definitions, Using a label and text box to confirm the `DataContext` is bubbling out updates, Any plausible `FrameworkMetadataPropertyOptions` (`AffectsRender`, `BindsTwoWayByDefault`), Explicitly setting `Binding Mode=TwoWay`, Beating head on wall, Changing `ValueProperty` to `EnumValueProperty` in case of conflict.

Any suggestions or ideas would be extremely appreciated, thanks for anything you can offer!

The enumeration:

```
[Flags]
public enum Department : byte
{
    None = 0x00,
    A = 0x01,
    B = 0x02,
    C = 0x04,
    D = 0x08
} // end enum Department
```

The XAML usage:

```
CheckBox Name="studentIsInDeptACheckBox"
         ctrl:CheckBoxFlagsBehaviour.Mask="{x:Static c:Department.A}"
         ctrl:CheckBoxFlagsBehaviour.IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
         ctrl:CheckBoxFlagsBehaviour.Value="{Binding Department}"
```

The class:

```
/// <summary>
/// A helper class for providing bit-wise binding.
/// </summary>
public class CheckBoxFlagsBehaviour
{
    private static bool isValueChanging;

    public static Enum GetMask(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Enum)obj.GetValue(MaskProperty);
    } // end GetMask

    public static void SetMask(DependencyObject obj, Enum value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(MaskProperty, value);
    } // end SetMask

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaskProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Mask", typeof(Enum),
        typeof(CheckBoxFlagsBehaviour), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static Enum GetValue(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Enum)obj.GetValue(ValueProperty);
    } // end GetValue

    public static void SetValue(DependencyObject obj, Enum value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
    } // end SetValue

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Value", typeof(Enum),
        typeof(CheckBoxFlagsBehaviour), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, ValueChanged));

    private static void ValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        isValueChanging = true;
        byte mask = Convert.ToByte(GetMask(d));
        byte value = Convert.ToByte(e.NewValue);

        BindingExpression exp = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(d, IsCheckedProperty);
        object dataItem = GetUnderlyingDataItem(exp.DataItem);
        PropertyInfo pi = dataItem.GetType().GetProperty(exp.ParentBinding.Path.Path);
        pi.SetValue(dataItem, (value & mask) != 0, null);

        ((CheckBox)d).IsChecked = (value & mask) != 0;
        isValueChanging = false;
    } // end ValueChanged

    public static bool? GetIsChecked(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool?)obj.GetValue(IsCheckedProperty);
    } // end GetIsChecked

    public static void SetIsChecked(DependencyObject obj, bool? value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value);
    } // end SetIsChecked

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsChecked", typeof(bool?),
        typeof(CheckBoxFlagsBehaviour), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, IsCheckedChanged));

    private static void IsCheckedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isValueChanging) return;

        bool? isChecked = (bool?)e.NewValue;
        if (isChecked != null)
        {
            BindingExpression exp = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(d, ValueProperty);
            object dataItem = GetUnderlyingDataItem(exp.DataItem);
            PropertyInfo pi = dataItem.GetType().GetProperty(exp.ParentBinding.Path.Path);

            byte mask = Convert.ToByte(GetMask(d));
            byte value = Convert.ToByte(pi.GetValue(dataItem, null));

            if (isChecked.Value)
            {
                if ((value & mask) == 0)
                {
                    value = (byte)(value + mask);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ((value & mask) != 0)
                {
                    value = (byte)(value - mask);
                }
            }

            pi.SetValue(dataItem, value, null);
        }
    } // end IsCheckedChanged

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the underlying data item from an object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="o">The object to examine.</param>
    /// <returns>The underlying data item if appropriate, or the object passed in.</returns>
    private static object GetUnderlyingDataItem(object o)
    {
        return o is DataRowView ? ((DataRowView)o).Row : o;
    } // end GetUnderlyingDataItem
} // end class CheckBoxFlagsBehaviour
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You could use a value converter. Here's a very specific implementation for the target `Enum`, but would not be hard to see how to make the converter more generic:

```
[Flags]
public enum Department
{
    None = 0,
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 4,
    D = 8
}

public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DepartmentsPanel.DataContext = new DataObject
        {
            Department = Department.A | Department.C
        };
    }
}

public class DataObject
{
    public DataObject()
    {
    }

    public Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class DepartmentValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private Department target;

    public DepartmentValueConverter()
    {
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Department mask = (Department)parameter;
        this.target = (Department)value;
        return ((mask & this.target) != 0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        this.target ^= (Department)parameter;
        return this.target;
    }
}
```

And then use the converter in the XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <l:DepartmentValueConverter x:Key="DeptConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

 <StackPanel x:Name="DepartmentsPanel">
    <CheckBox Content="A"
              IsChecked="{Binding 
                            Path=Department,
                            Converter={StaticResource DeptConverter},
                            ConverterParameter={x:Static l:Department.A}}"/>
    <!-- more -->
 </StackPanel>
```

**EDIT:** I don't have enough "rep" (yet!) to comment below so I have to update my own post :(

In the last comment [Steve Cadwallader](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41693/steve-cadwallader) says: *"but when it comes to two-way binding the ConvertBack falls apart"*, well I've updated my sample code above to handle the ConvertBack scenario; I've also posted a sample working application [***here***](http://www.box.net/shared/8xp0qqsc47) (**edit:** note that the sample code download also includes a generic version of the converter).

Personally I think this is a lot simpler, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Paul, but if there are multiple check boxes then the ConvertBack from any one of them will override and lose the data for the other bits.  It is the ConvertBack part that makes this a tricky problem.

Comment: Indeed, the sample is a little simplistic; however, I think this solution still applies as you could look at the incoming bool? value and then ^= the value based on mask supplied in the ConverterParameter; make sense? If not lemme know and I'll post some code when I get some time over the holidays.

Comment: Updated the post to include the ConvertBack scenario, also note that I've posted a link to a working copy of the application.

Comment: Your suggestion definitely does seem cleaner.  I avoid fields on a converter object because I'm not clear how WPF handles creating separate instances of converters.  If you had two sets of four check boxes for two copies of the enum - do you think your solution would work?

Comment: Absolutely! To make it all play nicely you'll need to create an instance of the converter for each "flags" value you need to convert. In my sample code above you would simply add another converter to the Windows.Resources section of the XAML, and you're done (obviously w/ a different x:Key value).

Comment: In Convert method change return value to: `return (mask == 0 && this.target == 0) ? true : ((mask & this.target) != 0);` to handle flag with value `0`

Comment: @PaulJ What if my checkboxes that need to bind to enum flag bits are being created in a DataTemplate inside of an ItemsControl? I can't create a separate instance of the converter for each flag because I don't know how many will need to be created, and I can't use the ConverterParameter to pass in the mask because ConverterParameter is not a DependencyProperty.

Comment: This still isn't answered :(  Cant have multiple checkboxes binding to different values on a page with the same converter I guess.

Comment: @user999999928 answer above works with multiple checkboxes

Comment: You could use this answer for multiple, independent sets of checkboxes by creating multiple instances of the converter in `<Window.Resources>` (i.e. write `<l:DepartmentValueConverter x:Key="DeptConverter1">`, `<l:DepartmentValueConverter x:Key="DeptConverter2">`, etc.)

Answer (score 6):

Here's something I came up with that leaves the View nice and clean (no static resources necessary, no new attached properties to fill out, no converters or converter parameters required in the binding), and leaves the ViewModel clean (no extra properties to bind to)

The View looks like this:

```
<CheckBox Content="A" IsChecked="{Binding Department[A]}"/>
<CheckBox Content="B" IsChecked="{Binding Department[B]}"/>
<CheckBox Content="C" IsChecked="{Binding Department[C]}"/>
<CheckBox Content="D" IsChecked="{Binding Department[D]}"/>
```

The ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  private Department department;

  public ViewModel()
  {
    Department = new EnumFlags<Department>(department);
  }

  public Department Department { get; private set; }
}
```

If you're ever going to assign a new value to the Department property, don't. Leave Department alone. Write the new value to Department.Value instead.

This is where the magic happens (this generic class can be reused for any flag enum)

```
public class EnumFlags<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
  private T value;

  public EnumFlags(T t)
  {
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(T)} must be an enum type"); // I really wish they would just let me add Enum to the generic type constraints
    value = t;
  }

  public T Value
  {
    get { return value; }
    set
    {
      if (this.value.Equals(value)) return;
      this.value = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
    }
  }

  [IndexerName("Item")]
  public bool this[T key]
  {
    get
    {
      // .net does not allow us to specify that T is an enum, so it thinks we can't cast T to int.
      // to get around this, cast it to object then cast that to int.
      return (((int)(object)value & (int)(object)key) == (int)(object)key);
    }
    set
    {
      if ((((int)(object)this.value & (int)(object)key) == (int)(object)key) == value) return;

      this.value = (T)(object)((int)(object)this.value ^ (int)(object)key);

      OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
    }
  }

  #region INotifyPropertyChanged
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
  {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(memberName));
  }
  #endregion
}
```

Comment: Love it, simple and reuseable (f.e. in a shared Project). Also, you can add localized strings for every enum value as Bonus feature. The only thing, that bothers me is the missing value check in XAML (i.e. mistyped values)...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for everyone's help, I finally figured it out.

I am binding to a strongly typed DataSet, so the enumerations are stored as type System.Byte and not System.Enum.  I happened to notice a silent binding casting exception in my debug output window which pointed me to this difference.  The solution is the same as above, but with the ValueProperty being of type Byte instead of Enum.

Here is the CheckBoxFlagsBehavior class repeated in its final revision.  Thanks again to Ian Oakes for the original implementation!

```
public class CheckBoxFlagsBehaviour
{
    private static bool isValueChanging;

    public static Enum GetMask(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Enum)obj.GetValue(MaskProperty);
    } // end GetMask

    public static void SetMask(DependencyObject obj, Enum value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(MaskProperty, value);
    } // end SetMask

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaskProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Mask", typeof(Enum),
        typeof(CheckBoxFlagsBehaviour), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static byte GetValue(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (byte)obj.GetValue(ValueProperty);
    } // end GetValue

    public static void SetValue(DependencyObject obj, byte value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
    } // end SetValue

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Value", typeof(byte),
        typeof(CheckBoxFlagsBehaviour), new UIPropertyMetadata(default(byte), ValueChanged));

    private static void ValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        isValueChanging = true;
        byte mask = Convert.ToByte(GetMask(d));
        byte value = Convert.ToByte(e.NewValue);

        BindingExpression exp = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(d, IsCheckedProperty);
        object dataItem = GetUnderlyingDataItem(exp.DataItem);
        PropertyInfo pi = dataItem.GetType().GetProperty(exp.ParentBinding.Path.Path);
        pi.SetValue(dataItem, (value & mask) != 0, null);

        ((CheckBox)d).IsChecked = (value & mask) != 0;
        isValueChanging = false;
    } // end ValueChanged

    public static bool? GetIsChecked(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool?)obj.GetValue(IsCheckedProperty);
    } // end GetIsChecked

    public static void SetIsChecked(DependencyObject obj, bool? value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value);
    } // end SetIsChecked

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsChecked", typeof(bool?),
        typeof(CheckBoxFlagsBehaviour), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, IsCheckedChanged));

    private static void IsCheckedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isValueChanging) return;

        bool? isChecked = (bool?)e.NewValue;
        if (isChecked != null)
        {
            BindingExpression exp = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(d, ValueProperty);
            object dataItem = GetUnderlyingDataItem(exp.DataItem);
            PropertyInfo pi = dataItem.GetType().GetProperty(exp.ParentBinding.Path.Path);

            byte mask = Convert.ToByte(GetMask(d));
            byte value = Convert.ToByte(pi.GetValue(dataItem, null));

            if (isChecked.Value)
            {
                if ((value & mask) == 0)
                {
                    value = (byte)(value + mask);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ((value & mask) != 0)
                {
                    value = (byte)(value - mask);
                }
            }

            pi.SetValue(dataItem, value, null);
        }
    } // end IsCheckedChanged

    private static object GetUnderlyingDataItem(object o)
    {
        return o is DataRowView ? ((DataRowView)o).Row : o;
    } // end GetUnderlyingDataItem
} // end class CheckBoxFlagsBehaviour
```

Comment: This seems awfully complex - why wouldn't a simple value converter do the job?

Comment: A value converter is great for one-way binding, but when it comes to two-way binding the ConvertBack falls apart because you can't know what the other bits are set to in order to return a valid value.

Answer (score 1):

Check your DataObject which binds to the CheckBoxes contains Department property has an INotifyPropertyChnaged.PropertyChanged called on its Setter?

Comment: I am binding to a strongly typed DataRow which does successfully publish PropertyChanged events.  I confirmed this by binding it to other UI controls (Label, TextBox) which would update correctly.

Thank you for the suggestion though. :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough rep to comment yet, this solution is targeting user99999991:
"Cant have multiple checkboxes binding to different values on a page with the same converter I guess."
Another advantage, with this solution you can also bind the Flag mask instead of hardcoding a static reference.

Using a IMultiValueConverter:

```
public class FlagToBoolConverter : IMultiValueConverter

{
    private YourFlagEnum selection;
    private YourFlagEnum mask;

    public static int InstanceCount = 0;

    public FlagToBoolConverter()
    {
        InstanceCount++;
    }

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        mask = (YourFlagEnum ) values[1];
        selection = (YourFlagEnum ) values[0];
        return (mask & selection) != 0;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.Equals(true))
        {
            selection |= mask;
        }
        else
        {
            selection &= ~mask;
        }

        object[] o = new object[2];
        o[0] = selection;
        o[1] = mask;
        return o;
    }
}
```

ItemsControl (CheckBoxTemplates is a List, so you can add multiple Checkboxes during Runtime):

```
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CheckBoxTemplates}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="40,0,0,0"></StackPanel>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Content}" >
                                        <CheckBox.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                                                <Setter Property="IsChecked">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FlagToBoolConverter}">
                                                            <Binding Path="MyEnumProperty" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"></Binding>
                                                            <Binding Path="MyEnumPropertyMask"></Binding>
                                                        </MultiBinding>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                            </Style>
                                        </CheckBox.Style>
                                    </CheckBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
```

Important: When declaring the converter, set x:Shared="False" so that multiple instances are created:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ui:FlagToBoolConverter x:Key="FlagToBoolConverter" x:Shared="False"></ui:FlagToBoolConverter>
</UserControl.Resources>
```