# Value Converter with Dependency Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, converters

I have problems implementing a custom DependencyObject:

I need a converter which sets or unsets a enum flag in a bound property. Therefore I created a IValueConverter derieved from FrameworkElement with two DependencyProperties: Flag (the flag which is set/unset by the converter) and Flags (the value/property to modify). The parent UserControl (Name = EnumerationEditor) provides the property to which the converter is bound.

A ListBox generates CheckBoxes and the converter instances which are used to modify the property via a DataTemplate. Each CheckBox/converter instance is used for one flag. I use the following XAML code:

```xml
<ListBox Name="Values" SelectionMode="Extended" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Padding="5">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:Enum}">

            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <Label x:Key="myTestResource" x:Shared="False"
                            Content="{Binding}"
                            ToolTip="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=EnumerationEditor}"
                            Foreground="{Binding Path=Background, ElementName=EnumerationEditor}"
                            Background="{Binding Path=Foreground, ElementName=EnumerationEditor}"/>
                <converters:EnumerationConverter x:Key="EnumerationConverter" x:Shared="False"
                                                    Flag="{Binding}"
                                                    Flags="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=EnumerationEditor}"/>
            </DataTemplate.Resources>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=EnumerationEditor, Converter={StaticResource EnumerationConverter}}"/>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource myTestResource}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**The strange thing: The Label works fine - but the converter does not.** I get the error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=EnumerationEditor'. BindingExpression:Path=Value; DataItem=null; target element is 'EnumerationConverter' (Name=''); target property is 'Flags' (type 'Enum')

I don't understand why, the binding is basically the same...

Here is the code for the converter:

```
public class EnumerationConverter : FrameworkElement, IValueConverter
{

    #region IValueConverter

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Parity.Space;
    }

    #endregion

    #region public Enum Flag { get; set; }

    public Enum Flag
    {
        get { return (Enum)this.GetValue(EnumerationConverter.FlagProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(EnumerationConverter.FlagProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dependency property for Flag.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FlagProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Flag", typeof(Enum), typeof(EnumerationConverter));

    #endregion

    #region public Enum Flags { get; set; }

    public Enum Flags
    {
        get { return (Enum)this.GetValue(EnumerationConverter.FlagsProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(EnumerationConverter.FlagsProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dependency property for Flags.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FlagsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Flags", typeof(Enum), typeof(EnumerationConverter));

    #endregion

}
```

Comment: is EnumerationEditor part of your usercontrol, you have posted only the listbox

Comment: @anivas: Yes, it is the UserControl itself. It has a dependecy Property called Value of type Enum. But as you can see in the snippets, I use the exact same binding for Label.ToolTip as for the Converter. The Label.ToolTip works - it displays the correct value. But the converter produces the error.

Comment: Converters will not be part of the visual tree, thats why it couldnt find it. what are you trying to do?

Comment: @anivas: I'm trying to create an editor for a enum typed Property (with Flags attribute). The user should be able to select the flags using the checkboxes. The converter should set/clear the specific flag in the property and determine if a flag is set.

Comment: You are better off with a multivalueconverter, so that you can send whatever binding you want.

Comment: @anivas: Still the same problem - when converting (flag, flags) to (bool) it's simple and works. But how to convert back? input is (bool) only, so I can't determine the current value to set/clear the flag. I'd still need ad DP to find the current value. Remember, i don't want to set the value to a single flag, I want to modify a single flag only.

Comment: Its should still be DP of checkbox and not converter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326802/how-can-you-two-way-bind-a-checkbox-to-an-individual-bit-of-a-flags-enumeration

Comment: @anivas: Thanks for the link - the example provided works if I create the check boxes by hand. But the ConverterParameter can not be bound - so I still have the same problem. I don't know the exact enum Type to use at compile time, so I have to create the checkboxes from code. It seems there is no good way to do this in XAML, so'll fall back to C# code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Conclusion**

I decided to solve the problem using two UserControls; FlagControl and EnumerationEditorControl.

The FlagControl has two dependency properties

- Flag (System.Enum): Determines which flag is set/cleared by the control
- Value(System.Enum): Bound to the propery/value in which the flag is set/cleared.

The EnumerationEditorControl has one dependency property:

- Value(System.Enum): The propery/value in which flags are set.

The EnumerationEditorControl uses a DataTemplate to instantiate FlagControls. The DataTemplate binds the FlagControl.Flag property to the DataContext and the FlagControl.Value property to the EnumerationEditorControl.Value property.

This way I don't need a converter and logic is clearly separated.

Thanks for the suggestions, comments and replies!

Answer (score 7):

A converter is not a `FrameworkElement` so it should not inherit from that class, at best use `DependencyObject`.

Since the converter is not in any tree that binding will not work, you can try:

```xml
<converters:EnumerationConverter x:Key="EnumerationConverter" x:Shared="False"
                                 Flag="{Binding}"
                                 Flags="{Binding Path=Value, Source={x:Reference EnumerationEditor}}"/>
```

(However this should be placed in the `Resources` of the `UserControl` and referenced, otherwise the [`x:Reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380.aspx) will cause a cyclical dependency error.)

Note that the `Flag` binding tries to bind to the `DataContext` which might not work as the `DataContext` may not be inherited for the same reasons that `ElementName` and `RelativeSource` will not work.

Comment: You are completely right - the Flag binding does not work. But I can use the x:Reference solution for both items and now it works. But I get lots of System.Windows.Data Errors (6/23). Need to trace down the errors but you pointed me to the right direction, thanks!