# ConvertBack value isn't set correctly when UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit (representing enum with checkboxes)

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, checkbox, enums

[Edit: this is now solved, albeit with an outstanding query - see updates.]

I'm developing a small WPF application - an alarm clock - and have a problem with representing my WeekDays enum as checkboxes in my Alarm Editor window. Specifically, the value parameter of my value converter's ConvertBack method doesn't reflect the value of each checkbox's IsChecked Property. However, this problem only appears when the checkboxes' UpdateSourceTriggers settings are set to Explicit (which is necessary), as opposed to PropertyChanged or LostFocus. The upshot is that a user cannot save changes to the days when the alarm should be triggered.

Here's my enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum Weekdays { Sun = 1, Mon = 2, Tue = 4, Wed = 8, Thu = 16, Fri = 32, Sat = 64 }
```

I'm using a value converter based on the code in the accepted answer to this question: [How can you two-way bind a checkbox to an individual bit of a flags enumeration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326802/how-can-you-two-way-bind-a-checkbox-to-an-individual-bit-of-a-flags-enumeration/375288#375288). This code worked pretty much as is (apart from changing 'Department' to 'Weekdays') except that it cannot work with UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit. The amendments I made to the ConvertBack method are intended to fix this, and I believe they should and that my problem lies elsewhere:

```
namespace Prog
{
    public class WeekDayValueConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        private Weekdays target;

        public WeekDayValueConverter()
        {
        }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Weekdays mask = (Weekdays)parameter;
            this.target = (Weekdays)value;
            return ((mask & this.target) != 0);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Weekdays mask = (Weekdays)parameter;
            this.target &= ~mask;
            if ((bool)value) this.target |= mask;
            return this.target;
        }
    }
}
```

Some xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:WeekDayValueConverter x:Key="WDVConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbSun" Content="Sunday" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Alarm.Days, Converter={StaticResource WDVConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:Weekdays.Sun}, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="476,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbMon" Content="Monday" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Alarm.Days, Converter={StaticResource WDVConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:Weekdays.Mon}, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="476,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbTue" Content="Tuesday" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Alarm.Days, Converter={StaticResource WDVConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:Weekdays.Tue}, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="476,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbWed" Content="Wednesday" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Alarm.Days, Converter={StaticResource WDVConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:Weekdays.Wed}, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="476,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbThu" Content="Thursday" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Alarm.Days, Converter={StaticResource WDVConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:Weekdays.Thu}, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="476,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbFri" Content="Friday" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Alarm.Days, Converter={StaticResource WDVConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:Weekdays.Fri}, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="476,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbSat" Content="Saturday" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Alarm.Days, Converter={StaticResource WDVConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:Weekdays.Sat}, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="476,140,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

And finally, the code behind. I've included everything that could be pertinent, and more, but the binding source updates are the most relevant and they're in my Save button's click event:

```
    namespace Prog
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for AlarmEditor.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class AlarmEditor : Window
    {
        public ObservableAlarmList Oal { get; set; }
        int ixOal;
        public Alarm Alarm { get; set; }
        bool updating;

        public AlarmEditor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public AlarmEditor(ObservableAlarmList oal, int ixOal)
            : this()
        {
            Oal = oal;
            this.ixOal = ixOal;
            updating = true;

            Alarm = oal.FindByOalIndex(ixOal);

            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private void bSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BindingExpression binding;
            binding = this.tbActive.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
            binding.UpdateSource();
            binding = this.tbAlarmName.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
            binding.UpdateSource();
            binding = this.comChannel.GetBindingExpression(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty);
            binding.UpdateSource();
            binding = this.cbSun.GetBindingExpression(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty);
            binding.UpdateSource();
            binding = this.cbMon.GetBindingExpression(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty);
            binding.UpdateSource();
            binding = this.cbTue.GetBindingExpression(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty);
            binding.UpdateSource();
            binding = this.cbWed.GetBindingExpression(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty);
            binding.UpdateSource();
            binding = this.cbThu.GetBindingExpression(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty);
            binding.UpdateSource();
            binding = this.cbFri.GetBindingExpression(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty);
            binding.UpdateSource();
            binding = this.cbSat.GetBindingExpression(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty);
            binding.UpdateSource();
            binding = this.comDevice.GetBindingExpression(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty);
            binding.UpdateSource();
            binding = this.tbRampMins.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
            binding.UpdateSource();
            binding = this.tbRepeat.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
            binding.UpdateSource();
            binding = this.tbSleepMins.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
            binding.UpdateSource();
            binding = this.tbHour.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
            binding.UpdateSource();
            binding = this.tbMinute.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
            binding.UpdateSource();
            binding = this.tbVolEnd.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
            binding.UpdateSource();
            binding = this.tbVolStart.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
            binding.UpdateSource();
            if (updating)
                Oal.UpdateAlarm(ixOal, Alarm);
            else Oal.AddAlarm(Alarm);
            this.Close();
        }

        private void bCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Stepping through ConvertBack in two different scenarios I see this behaviour:

First scenario: UpdateSourceTrigger != Explicit and a checkbox is toggled:

- this.target shows the days as shown in the editor prior to the toggle (e.g. Tue | Wed | Thu | Sat)
- value is correctly set (e.g. false)
- the ConvertBack logic correctly sets this.target according to the change
- No problem.

Second scenario: UpdateSourceTrigger == Explicit, checkboxes are randomly toggled and Save is clicked. ConvertBack will be called seven times as part of Save routine, starting on cbSun:

The first time is the same as above, it works correctly (which I left out of the intro for simplicity):

- this.target shows the days as originally loaded into the editor
- value (i.e. Sunday's value) is set correctly, according to the value shown in the editor prior to the Save
- this.target correctly updates to show an updated Weekdays value (adding Sun, removing Sun, or no change)

Subsequent iterations do NOT work correctly:

- this.target is not the problem, it is trying to keep the running set of Weekdays, but it cannot, because...
- value does not show the value set in the window. Instead it shows the original, unaltered value.

I'd be very grateful for an explanation or a solution. Why does ConvertBack only supply the correct value the first time it's called?

Thanks,

Matthew

**UPDATE:**

On further investigation I see the problem. When the Save routine gets to this bit:

```
binding = this.cbSun.GetBindingExpression(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty);
binding.UpdateSource();
```

the source is updated, whereupon the targets are updated. This means all user changes are lost apart from any change to the first target (Sunday in my code).

What I would like is a combination of OneTime and OneWayToSource binding: Targets should be initialised from the source, but are not subsequently updated from the source, and the source is updated from the targets upon save. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

**SOLVED - but still a query:**

In the end I've got it working by doing just this:

- setting the binding mode of each checkbox to OneWayToSource.
- manually initialising the checkboxes as follows:

  `cbSun.IsChecked = (Alarm.Days & Weekdays.Sun) != 0;
  cbMon.IsChecked = (Alarm.Days & Weekdays.Mon) != 0;
  // etc.`

I'm glad it's working, but it seems a shame not to be able to use the binding infrastructure for initialisation. The value converter stuff is really neat, but I've now had to implement the conversion logic in two places, once in the value converter, and once in my initialisation code.

I would have thought that the scenario here is pretty common: an editor window where values need to be loaded from some collection, then messed around with by the user, and only committed back to the collection once the user clicks Save. But there's no binding mode that supports this and I've had to hack around the lack of it. I'm new to WPF so I may well be missing something - I'd like to know if there's any better approach which makes use of the value converter in both directions.

Otherwise, hopefully this little tweak to PaulJ's approach (from the linked question at the beginning), which is necessary in the case where UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, will be useful.